# Non-ASCII characters in IE download dialog, using Drupal6/Filedepot

Tags: internet-explorer, drupal, drupal-modules, non-ascii-characters

I'm using Drupal6 and Filedepot module to store files into Drupal. Downloading files works perfectly with Firefox and Chrome, but there's some annoying problems with Internet Explorer.

If the filename contains non-ASCII characters, as many finnish words do, it messes up the whole filename. For example, when downloading "Alykkäät teknologiat.doc", IE wants to save the the file with the following name: "=_UTF-8_B_bHlra8Okw6R0IHRla25vbG9naWF0LmRvYw==_=".

Is there a way to convert that string easily back to "normal" string?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the best compatibility between servers, old browsers and foreign users you probably want to transliterate your file names. http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths can do it for you (on upload).